# How do I attach a dynamic Broadcast Receiver in a pending intent?

Tags: android

I have a Broadcast Receiver object and I want it to be called when a notification is clicked. I'm previously using static (in manifest) but it doesn't fit my purpose.

In the static way, I can just do, for example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(app, DictReceiver.class);
```

But I don't think I can do that in the dynamic one.
Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, you have to use implicit `Intent`s with dynamically registered `BroadcastReceiver`s. That is, create your `Intent` with an action `String`, and use that same action for the `IntentFilter`.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little? For example, can I use any string or do I need to use some Intent.CONSTANT strings? Thank you.

Comment: A common way to create an action `String` is to use your package name and append some meaningful, terse description of the action on the end. E.g., `"com.mycompany.myapp.NOTIFICATION_CLICK"`. In this way, you could then easily change the description for different actions, if you need, and there's very little chance of it clashing with another app's actions.

Comment: I got it. Thank you.

Comment: Note that this will only work if the `PendingIntent` is executed while your process is running and the receiver is registered. If your process is not running, if something executes the `PendingIntent`, the broadcast will go out, nothing will be registered for it, and the event will be ignored.